# sum of 2 different columns in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables A and B. The columns names are similar in both the tables. The columns are

```
1. fees
2. user_id
```

I want to get the sum of `fees` from both tables where `user_id = 1`

For eg:

**Table A:**

```
id           user_id      fees
1            1            10
2            2            11
3            1            5
```

**Table B:**

```
id           user_id      fees
1            1            15
2            2            10
3            1            20
```

I need the **result** as below:

```
user_id     fees
1           50
2           21
```

Please help me with the query

Comment: Do a UNION ALL. GROUP BY its result.

Comment: But why do you have two identical tables?

Comment: select a.user_id, sum(a.fees+b.fees) from table1 a, table2 b where a.user_id = b.user_id group by a.user_id;

Comment: Your example result does not make sense to me

Comment: The result is just as expected. 10 + 5 + 15 + 20 = 50, and 11 + 10 = 21.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select user_id, sum(fees) from (
  select user_id, fees from Table_A
  union all
  select user_id, fees from Table_B
) as A
group by user_id
```